# Spring-boot Actuator endpoints - 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, http-status-code-406

I am getting a 406 Not Acceptable error for my spring-boot actuator endpoints like /health, /env, /info etc

I am using spring-boot version 1.5.8

Accessing endpoints like
http://localhost:6061/health
http://localhost:6061/env

Here is bits of my gradle build file

```
buildscript {            
ext {            
    springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'            
}                
dependencies {                        
    classpath(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot- 
gradle-plugin', version:'1.5.8.RELEASE')            
}            
}                  
repositories {            
mavenLocal()            
maven {            
    url "${artifactory_url}" + "libs-release"            
    credentials {            
        username = "${artifactory_user}"            
        password = "${artifactory_password}"            
    }            
}            
maven {            
    url "${artifactory_url}" + "libs-snapshot"            
    credentials {            
        username = "${artifactory_user}"            
        password = "${artifactory_password}"            
    }            
}                   
}       
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'            
 apply plugin: 'java'                                 
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'            
apply plugin: 'project-report'     
dependencies {               
compile("org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.4")            
runtime 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'                        
 compile fileTree(dir: 'src/libs/', include: '*.jar')                      
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:1.2.2.RELEASE")            
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix- 
dashboard:1.3.1.RELEASE')            
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter- 
hystrix:1.3.1.RELEASE')            
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter- 
eureka:1.3.1.RELEASE')            
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter- 
turbine:1.3.1.RELEASE')                  
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
```

Comment: I presume the question would be how to access endpoints successfully? Can you update the ticket with how you are accessing the endpoint?

Comment: @Boris Added the comment above, accessing this endpoint http://localhost:6061/health

Comment: Can you also add the application properties file? Do you have any actuator related settings?

Comment: @Boris I do not have any actuator related settings in my application.properties.

Comment: Do you send an Accept header with your request? Maybe try json instead of xml or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot actuator endpoints are typically exposed via HTTP and are mapped to a URL with a prefix of `/actuator`. For example, by default, the `health` endpoint is mapped to `/actuator/health`.

If your application is running locally on port **6061**, the correct URLs will be:

```
http://localhost:6061/actuator/health
http://localhost:6061/actuator/env
```

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints) for more details. You can also [customize the prefix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-management-server-context-path) for the management endpoints in **application.properties**, for example:

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/manage
```

This changes the endpoint from `/actuator/{id}` to `/manage/{id}`.